# 2D raycast on mobile is giving weird results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, 2d

I'm trying to detect a simple tap on collider in a prototype I'm developing with Unity. The problem is that while it detects the collision it seems to do so way off target at times.

Here is what I have

```
Vector2 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(point, Vector2.zero);
if (hit.collider != null)
{
          //Do stuff
}
```

I expect that it would only go off on the colliders alone.
I added a little text log to make sure it's not hitting other things.

Here's a little image to explain. Blue is where the tapping should be recognized, red is where I tap with my finger and it still recognizes it like I had hit blue. https://gyazo.com/7462de174d30b2d81a30c17f2bbc62fa

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Isn't the 2nd argument for `Physics2D.Raycast(Vector2, Vector2)` a direction? `Vector2.zero` sounds like a strange direction to me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the issues. I'll post it here in case anyone else stumble on this kind of issue and can't seem to have it work.

Simply put, check your camera transform. Mine somehow had an offset of 1 in the Y and it was messing everything up.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```cs
Vector3 screenTouchPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
screenTouchPos.z = 1f; // distance to the camera

Vector2 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenTouchPos);
```

Explanation here: [ScreenToWorldPoint() not working](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1236547/problem-with-screentoworldpointinputmouseposition.html)

> ScreenToWorldPoint receives a Vector3 argument where x and y are the screen coordinates, and z is the distance from the camera. Since Input.mousePosition.z is always 0, what you're getting is the camera position.

---

Precision: that should only be an issue with a *perspective* camera projection, not with an *orthographic* projection.

---

EDIT: Since this does not solve your problem, here are few tips to debug it (I don't have enough info on your case to suggest anything):

- Use `Debug.DrawLine` to check if `Vector2 point` has a correct value

  - If so, check that your colliders have the right size/position.
  - If not, use `Camera.ViewportPointToRay` in conjunction with `Debug.DrawLine` to see if the ray is correct.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I tried that but it doesn't seem to change anything.  I'm indeed using an ortographic camera and everything is at 0 in the Z

Comment: Update: I checked in a new clean scene and it works just fine. So it's probably something in my scene that is creating issues

Comment: Oh alright! Well I added troubleshooting info, I think drawing the ray would have helped you see that the camera was misplaced.

Comment: You're welcome! Btw I think you should mark your own answer as being the solution to your question.